# If $g'(0)>0$ write this expression $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(f(x))}{\sin(g(x))}$ using $f(0),f'(0)$ and $g(0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, trigonometry

If $g'(0)>0$ write this expression $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(f(x))}{\sin(g(x))}$ using $f(0),f'(0)$ and $g(0)$.

This came up in my Analysis 1 exam, and i couldn't do it.

Comment: You should always share your own attempts on solving the problem. Apart from that, you can start seeing what keeps you from computing the limit. For instance, if $g(0)\ne 0$ and $f,g$ are continuous there is no indetermination and the limit is simply $\sin(f(0))/\sin(g(0))$. Can you continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression is not determined if and only if $f(0)=g(0)=0$Use Hospital, the limit is

${{f'(0)cos(f(0)}\over{g'(0)cosg(0)}}={{f'(0)}\over{g'(0)}}.$